# Is there any lodash method to update an object inside an array, where the item matched is going to have a new key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Im adding a checkbox options and only have to update my object with a new key

so if I uncheck a item in a list i want to update the object

```
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ]
```

after unchecked:

```
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2, unChecked: false } ]
```

any method to toggle this states?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using native javascript and array `map` method. In the function check if the `id` matches then add the key there

```js
let obj = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}]


function updateObj(obj, objId, key) {
  return obj.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === objId) {
      return {
        id: item.id,
        [key]: false
      }

    } else {
      return {
        id: item.id
      }
    }
  })
}

console.log(updateObj(obj, 2, 'unchecked'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without lodash and using the `.map` method by adding the `unChecked` property if the `id` is not in the `checked` array by using `.includes()`.

See working example below:

```js
const checked = [2, 3], /* array holding all checked values */
arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}],
res = arr.map(({id}) => checked.includes(id) ? {id, unChecked: false} : {id});

console.log(res);
```